# How to parameterize checkout of Branch in a Build-Job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I want to parameterize the checkout of a specific branch in jenkins.

This is what I did:

1. Clicked This project is parameterized
   [image]
2. No I want to use this variable in the checkout section:
   [image]

But this doesn't work. The variable isn't resolved by Jenkins.

Any Idea how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using pipeline? Can you post a screenshot with all parameter for the Git section?

Comment: Yeah I am using pipeline. Will post a screenshot - wait a Moment.

Comment: Thanks, added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable Lightweight checkout. From the help button next to it:

> If selected, try to obtain the Pipeline script contents directly from
>   the SCM without performing a full checkout. The advantage of this mode
>   is its efficiency; however, you will not get any changelogs or polling
>   based on the SCM. (If you use checkout scm during the build, this will
>   populate the changelog and initialize polling.) Also build parameters
>   will not be substituted into SCM configuration in this mode. Only
>   selected SCM plugins support this mode.

Comment: Do I have to change my Jenkinsfile when i disable Lightweight checkout?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :-)

Comment: One more Question. Can this variable be Resolved in a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: No worries. Yep, it will be available inside your Groovy script. Just using GIT_BRANCH as a normal variable will work.